# Run user-provided code from my framework

Tags: java, frameworks

I'm working on a Java framework and would like to allow the user to write some code and send it to my framework, where it would be run intermittently by my framework manager based on some factors. I'm basically looking to do something similar to what Swing uses when a button is clicked. I've searched and haven't found any way to implement this myself, so is there some design method I can use to achieve  this?

Swing example:

```
showDialogButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    // display/center the jdialog when the button is pressed
    JDialog d = new JDialog(frame, "Hello", true);
    d.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
    d.setVisible(true);
  }
});
```

Comment: You mean an interface and standard plugin pattern?

Comment: Maybe? Even searching that in Google yields very little results, and none that seem like what I'm trying to do. I want the user to be able to say `new ClassName () {}` and enter their own code in the body, and have my framework use their code as it sees fit.

Comment: Oh, you want to compile it on the fly?

Comment: No, the user would import my library and write their own file and compile it. Like how you would bind code to an event in Java Swing